# How can I use echo inside a TD element of an HTML table?

Tags: php, html

This is the image:

[image: tax invoice]

I have to use echo inside a `td` element of an HTML table. When I am trying this, it is showing an angle bracket error. How can I avoid that error? Below is my code.

```
<tr>
      <td>Net Amount</td>
      <td><b>'.$order_data['net_amount'].'</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   $number = $order_data['net_amount'];
   $no = round($number);
   $point = round($number - $no, 2) * 100;
   $hundred = null;
   $digits_1 = strlen($no);
   $i = 0;
   $str = array();
   $words = array('0' => '', '1' => 'One', '2' => 'Two',
    '3' => 'Three', '4' => 'Four', '5' => 'Five', '6' => 'Six',
    '7' => 'Seven', '8' => 'Eight', '9' => 'Nine',
    '10' => 'Ten', '11' => 'Eleven', '12' => 'Twelve','13' => 'Thirteen',
    '14' => 'Fourteen', '15' => 'Fifteen', '16' => 'Sixteen',
    '17' => 'Seventeen','18' => 'Eighteen', '19' =>'Nineteen', 
    '20' => 'Twenty','30' => 'Thirty', '40' => 'Forty', 
    '50' => 'Fifty','60' => 'Sixty', '70' => 'Seventy',
    '80' => 'Eighty', '90' => 'Ninety');
   $digits = array('', 'Hundred', 'Thousand', 'Lakh', 'Crore');
   while ($i < $digits_1) {
     $divider = ($i == 2) ? 10 : 100;
     $number = floor($no % $divider);
     $no = floor($no / $divider);
     $i += ($divider == 10) ? 1 : 2;
     if ($number) {
        $plural = (($counter = count($str)) && $number > 9) ? 's' : null;
        $hundred = ($counter == 1 && $str[0]) ? ' and ' : null;
        $str [] = ($number < 21) ? $words[$number] .
            " " . $digits[$counter] . $plural . " " . $hundred
            :
            $words[floor($number / 10) * 10]
            . " " . $words[$number % 10] . " "
            . $digits[$counter] . $plural . " " . $hundred;
     } else $str[] = null;
  }
  $str = array_reverse($str);
  $result = implode('', $str);
  $points = ($point) ?
    "." . $words[$point / 10] . " " . 
          $words[$point = $point % 10] : '';
    echo '<td colspan="7"> INR '.$result.' '.$points.'Only</td>';
  </tr>
```

Comment: So show us what you've tried.

Comment: You have a trailing single quote at the end of all that.

Comment: I have put screenshot in my question for better understanding of question.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from PHP trying to parse your `<td` as a statement.

You can't mix simple HTML with PHP. You can either wrap the HTML in an `echo` or `print` statement or end the PHP tag and restart it again:

*Method 1:*

```
    $words[$point = $point % 10] : '';
echo '<td colspan="7"> ...';
echo "INR " .$result. $points ."Only";
echo '</td>';
```

*Method 2:*

```
    $words[$point = $point % 10] : '';
?>
<td colspan="7"> ...
    <?php echo "INR " .$result. $points ."Only"; ?>
</td>
```

Comment: Method 1 worked but result is printing out of table.

Comment: Generate the table inside `php` section and add the `<td>` where ever you want. Else inject into the `<td>` using javascipt by accessing using `id` or `class` after the table is generated.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would to echo the `.

So for your code, something like this would work:

```
<?php
    echo '<td colspan="7"> INR '.$result.' '.$points.'Only</td>';
?>
```

Comment: It is showing syntax error, unexpected 'colspan' (T_STRING)

Comment: $points = ($point) ?
    "." . $words[$point / 10] . " " . 
          $words[$point = $point % 10] : '';
  <?php
    echo '<td colspan="7"> INR '.$result.' '.$points.'Only</td>';'
 ?>
  </tr>

Comment: Get rid of the last character `'` after the semicolon `;`

Comment: Now it is showing error in opening angle bracket of php(<?php)

Comment: @RuchirShah Sorry, since you already have an opening for PHP, you need to remove `<?php` and `?>`.

Comment: After removing php brackets it is printing out of table

Comment: @RuchirShah what are you talking about? Is it working?

Comment: It is working perfectly but output is printing out of table.

Comment: @RuchirShah Please post your whole/complete code in your original post and I will check it for you:

Comment: @RuchirShah Can you show an updated screenshot of the current result?

Comment: I have put new screenshot of my result

Answer (score 0):

Simply start php coding where ever you want to

```
<tr>
  <td>Net Amount</td>
  <td><b><?php echo $order_data['net_amount']?></b></td>
</tr>
```

Short hand code can be,

```
<tr>
  <td>Net Amount</td>
  <td><b><?=$order_data['net_amount']?></b></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can i write php inside php?

Comment: .php file can contain html code outside of "<?php ?>" tag and where ever you want to write php code , u need to write within "<?php ?> ".